# Scrapy not returning elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying in vain to retrieve data from here: https://www.etoro.com/discover/people/results. Let's say I want to get the nickname element first. It appears in the following format in the HTML source code: `<div _ngcontent-bqd-c27="" automation-id="trade-item-name" class="symbol">markaungier</div>`

I tried the following three approaches:

1. Using a CSS selector
   `nickname = response.css("[automation-id=trade-item-name]")`
2. Using an XPATH relative path
   `nickname = response.xpath("//div[@automation-id='trade-item-name']")`
3. Using a full XPATH
   `response.xpath("/html/body/ui-layout/div/div/div[2]/et-discovery-people-results/div/div/et-discovery-people-results-grid/div/div/div/et-user-card[1]/div/header/et-card-avatar/a/div[2]/div[1]")`

Strangely, none of them returned anything. What's going on here? Does the issue arise because of [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html), i.e. *"Some webpages show the desired data when you load them in a web browser. However, when you download them using Scrapy, you cannot reach the desired data using selectors"* ?

My full code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
import requests
from lxml import html
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class EtoroSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "traders"
    start_urls = [
         "https://www.etoro.com/discover/people/results",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        nickname = response.xpath("//div[@automation-id='trade-item-name']")
        print(nickname)

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(EtoroSpider)
process.start()
```

And here is the scrapy output:

```
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: adf8b7868ee25c32
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-14 16:29:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-14 16:29:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.etoro.com/discover/people/results> (referer: None)
[]
2020-10-14 16:29:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-14 16:29:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 236,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23288,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.353381,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 14, 29, 9, 150136),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 14, 29, 8, 796755)}
2020-10-14 16:29:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**EDIT**
I fetched the source code seen by Scrapy using `scrapy fetch --nolog https://www.etoro.com/discover/people/results > response.html` and found that it contains an injected JavaScript and has no trace of the above `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check ajax data fetching using network tab of development tools. There are couple of quite heavy responses in this case, most probably they contain the data needed.
So it can be fetched via API even not parsing the primary page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! However, what if the website's API is in alpha mode and they do not currently provide any API keys for users?

Comment: most of time you don't need any keys. You can just use directly sources of the data that front end does use. Just simulate front end requests and get pure JSON from the api.